# Snowflake data warehouse - querying data in staged files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

On running a query of staged data files in Snowflake, I have noticed that the filename effectively has an implicit glob on the end.

In other words,

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM @MASTERCATALOGUE.CUSTOMERS.USAGE_STAGE/4089.jsonl.gz
```

is actually

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM @MASTERCATALOGUE.CUSTOMERS.USAGE_STAGE/4089.jsonl.gz*
```

For example, I have two files in the stage named `4089.jsonl.gz` and `4089.jsonl.gz.1.gz`

On running the following:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM @MASTERCATALOGUE.CUSTOMERS.USAGE_STAGE/4089.jsonl.gz
```

I would expect to get the count of just `4089.jsonl.gz`. However, I get the count of both added together as the implicit glob ends up matching both files.

There is no mention of this in the documentation.

[Querying data in staged files](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-stage.html#file-formats)

I have tried putting single and double quotes around the filename, but this makes no difference.

Any ideas of the notation that will not add this implicit glob?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting single-quotes around the FROM portion?  Also, I see that you are not specifying a file format in your query.  Is there one attached to the stage?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the results by filtering on the METADATA$FILENAME metadata column:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM @MASTERCATALOGUE.CUSTOMERS.USAGE_STAGE/4089.jsonl.gz 
WHERE METADATA$FILENAME = '4089.jsonl.gz'
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-metadata.html#

Comment: METADATA$FILENAME has the full path, so the full path is required in where clause. Also depending on the stage type prefix `@` or `@~` might be required.